# trying to create simple login form in angular js ? i am getting an error " module fails to load due to some exception"

Tags: angularjs, validation

**index.html**

This is my index page. It gets loaded when my application runs, it contains prefilled values by default. I want to route to home page when a user submits the form after clicking the submit button. but i am getting an error [injector:moduler] this means that applications has failed to instantiate a module. below is my app.js file which contains a module and a controller kindly help me out to rectify this error.

```
  <body>
    <div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <form name="userForm"  ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
                        <h1>Login Form</h1> //a html form with validations in angular
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" value="ank@gmail.com">
                            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine }">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" value="1234">
                            <p ng-show="userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid password.</p>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**app.js**

```
    //this contains the modules and controllers.

    'use strict';

    // create angular app
    var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

    // create angular controller
    validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.submitForm = function() {
            var username = $scope.user.email;
            var password = $scope.user.password;
            if(username == "ank@gmail.com" && password=="1234")
            {
                if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                    alert('thank you for submitting your form');
                    window.location.href="home.html";
                }

            }
            else
            {
            alert("incorrect username and password");
            }
        };


    });

    //code for routing to another page after login

       validationApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/index', {
                    templateUrl: 'index.html',
                    controller: 'loginController'
                })
                .when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'home.html',
                    controller: 'RegisterController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/index'
                });
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to include `ngRoute` module.

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

check [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/routes.html) for more information about AngularJS Routes

Comment: i have tried adding this also but its not working, i have included these files also    :<link rel="text/javascript"  src="angular-route.min.js">
    <link rel="text/javascript"  src="angular-route.min.js.map">
    <link rel="text/javascript"  src="angular.min.js">
    <link rel="text/javascript"  src="angular.min.js.map">
in the header section

Comment: will you please update your question with the latest changes you have made? Do you still see the same error?

Comment: thanks Mehrdad you were right i forgot to mention ng-route , thanks nyways my code is working fine now.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer was true, please don't forget to accept it  as the true answer by clicking on the check mark ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.js

var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp',['ngRoute']);
validationApp.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'main.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/main.html'
            });
    });

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,$location,$window) {
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        var username = $scope.user.email;
        var password = $scope.user.password;
        var remember = $scope.user.rememberme;
        if(username == "ank@gmail.com" && password=="1234")
        {
            if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                alert('thank you for submitting your form');
                $location.path("/home");

            }

        }
        else
        {
            alert("invalid username and password");
        }
    };


});
```

i have also made changes in my index.html file

```
</head>
<body>
<div  ng-app="validationApp">
   <ng-view></ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

i have created another page for displaying my login form 
main.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <form name="userForm" method="post" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" value="ank@gmail.com">
                    <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine }">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" value="1234">
                    <p ng-show="userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid password.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.rememberme"
                           ng-true-value="yes" ng-false-value="no" > Remember Me
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```